# Get the database values on Notion (made with RollUp & Relation & Aggregation) -> to use in on integromat / make

Tags: make.com, notion, integromat-apps

I am using notion with Relation, roll up and aggregation to get some numbers -> pic 1

I want to retrieve those numbers to use them in excel (or else)

How can I do that (using make / integromat ?)

When I do it on make the output is the formula / the relation (not the value) -> pic 2

Thanks

[image]
[image]